# Unable to sideload application via .appinstaller file over https

Tags: c#, .net, https, msix, appinstaller

When trying to install application with .appinstaller I receive an error: "Error in parsing the app package." The install works if URI's are local. I have updated MIME types on the website. Application/Appx - .appx, Application/Msix - .msix, Application/Appinstaller - .appinstaller, etc. I have tried changing permissions on the files as well. The .msixbundle is downloaded and can be installed without .appinstaller. Also, I have tried installing it while on a different network, changing file names so that they don't have spaces dots underscores, I have tried restarting my computer. If I try to install an app after downloading the .appinstaller and running it locally I get a different error: "The .appinstaller file is invalid.".
Contents of the .appinstaller:

```
<AppInstaller
    Uri="https://website.com/Applications/AppName/Package/App.appinstaller"
    Version="1.0.22.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018">
    <MainBundle
        Name="1537d10e-3c54-4592-abdc-97712c37389d"
        Version="1.0.22.0"
        Publisher="CN=Company"
        Uri="https://website.com/Applications/AppName/Package/App_1.0.22.0_Test/App_1.0.22.0_AnyCPU.msixbundle" />
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0"
            ShowPrompt="true" />
        <AutomaticBackgroundTask />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for more details about the errros.  The appx or msix logs are displayed under the Application and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> AppXDeployment. You might want to clear the logs and try the deployment one more time for fresh logs.
You can also use the following tool during the deployment for assistance:
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-troubleshooter.html

Comment: I have checked the logs there is nothing of use there. The error provided is 0x80073CF0. The package is signed. Also once I got 0x80D05011  Unknown error.